# A sweet little riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

Here's a short little riddle.

```
You hang it on your tree. 
You can stir it in your tea. 
If you hap keep it handy, 
You can give it to your dame. 
Oh, it's a little ___________
```

Hint:

> Two words fill the blank ending in a rhyme. Happy Holidays, everyone!

Comment: *\*a-[HEM](https://i.imgur.com/9DdvBel.png)\**

Comment: My apologies @feelinferrety for the early submission. I'm just very thankful for Christmas. =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess but I think it might be

> Candy Cane

Because

> It is an item often associated with Christmas and used in all the ways described in the poem.

Comment: I got to this answer as well, and it's the first riddle here I was able to solve on my own. *Great Success!*

Comment: Ah, yes. How'd you guess? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I respect and props for earlier two answers, but here is mine

> Sugar/Cane *Candy*, as **rhyme** tag is prominent!

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't expect this answer. I can see what you mean. My intention though was that the last two words rhyme with "Handy" and "Dame" finishing in "Candy cane." Very creative though! +1

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but can it be a

> "candy cane"? 
>
>  [image]

Comment: You might want to consider putting your answer in spoiler tags

Comment: @Rob, I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: You got it! Unfortunately, hexomino got to it just before you, so I have to give the check to him. I appreciate the picture! It completes the festive post. +1

Comment: @Hawkeye, no problem at all. Thanks for your sweet riddle :)